# How to extract a specific field from output of tasklist on the windows command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd, tasklist

I ran the following command on the windows command prompt

```
C:>tasklist /fi "Imagename eq BitTorrent.exe"
```

The output of which is

```
Image Name            PID      Session Name       Session #    Mem Usage
==================  ======== =================   ===========   =========
BitTorrent.exe        6164      Console                   3     24,144K
```

I need to extract only one field, the PID, i.e. the number 6164 from the above output.

How do I achieve this ?
More generally, how do I extract a subset(1/more) of the fields from the output of a command on the windows command line ?

Answer (score 15):

Similar to previous answers, but uses specific switches in `tasklist` to skip header and behave correctly irrespective of spaces in image names:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %F in ('tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq BitTorrent.exe" /fo csv') do @echo %~F
```

(as run directly from cmd line, if run from batch replace `%F` with `%%F`

Comment: All 3 answers work for me, but i dont understand them :(
Can someone explain their code fragment or point me to documentation for 'for /f' , 'tokens', 'delims'

Comment: Run `'command'` in parens, then for each line of it's output:  tokenize (the line) with comma being delimiter and put a second token into %variable (`%F`) and then run `echo` with a given variable value (sans quotes, that's what tilde is for). For more general explanation on `for` syntax (including `for /f`) simply do `help for` at command line

Comment: @ashishmakani here is the documentation: https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html

Answer (score 10):

the easiest way is with using WMIC:

```
c:\>wmic process where caption="BitTorrent.exe" get  ProcessId
```

*EDIT:* As the WMIC is not part of **home** editions of windows:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %A in ('tasklist /fi ^"Imagename eq cmd.exe^" ^| find ^"cmd^"') do echo %B
```

Here is used CMD of the caption.You can change it in the find and tasklist parameters.
If this used in batch file you'll need `%%B` and `%%A`

Comment: i cant install anything on the machine & have to use the standard windows install.

Comment: wmic is a standard command for windows.Except home editions...I'll add other approches in my answer anyway.

Comment: PS: Remember you need to set right the tokens if the app filename contain spaces.

Comment: @Elektro Hacker - yes .If you need another field you'll have to define more tokens and access the right one.`tasklist -v` has 9 fields so the maximum possible tokens are 9 and the last filed will be accessible with  `%%H` if the first token is `%%A`

Comment: @npocmaka, did you make a minor typo in your comment above ?
For 9 fields, wont the 9th field be %%I & not %%H ?

Comment: WMIC doesnt do what we need if there is more than one proccess with the same name...

Comment: Yo bro but you command prints three lines. How do i print only the third line?

Answer (score 3):

You can use wmic command to not filter the output:

```
wmic process where name="BitTorrent.exe" get processid | MORE +1
```

UPDATE: Another way:

```
@Echo OFF
FOR /F "tokens=2" %%# in ('tasklist /fi "Imagename eq winamp.exe" ^| MORE +3') do (Echo %%#)
Pause&Exit
```

PS: Remember you need to set right the tokens if the app filename contain spaces.