# How to get a substring from a string in python 2

Tags: python, windows, string, list, python-2.7

I'm trying to get a substring from a string, it has to be specific though,
if you use this function and print it you'd get a long string with all the currently unresponsive processes and their infos, I need the PID from a specific process.

```
r = os.popen('tasklist /FI "STATUS eq Not Responding"').read().strip()  
print r
```

example if chrome.exe is not responding it would be in the list and I would like to get the PID associated with it. I tried `split()` and `pop()` to single out what I needed without success.

Edit :
I have 10+ processes that all share the same application name. 
It's necessary for me to use PID and that it belongs to the correct application. I don't want my script to kill everything either.

So in short I need to find the PID that is on the same row as the specified 'process_name' and then only keep that 'PID'

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Please post the "long string with all the currently unresponsive processes and their infos" and show us what you need from that string

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507902/how-to-extract-a-specific-field-from-output-of-tasklist-on-the-windows-command-l

Answer (score 5):

You can simplify your life by having tasklist return to you the list as a CSV:

```
C:\>tasklist /FI "STATUS eq Not Responding" /FO CSV /NH
"jusched.exe","3596","Console","1","13,352 K"
"chrome.exe","4760","Console","1","181,088 K"
"chrome.exe","3456","Console","1","119,044 K"
"chrome.exe","2432","Console","1","24,236 K"
"chrome.exe","440","Console","1","36,420 K"
"chrome.exe","4964","Console","1","60,596 K"
"chrome.exe","3608","Console","1","21,924 K"
"chrome.exe","4996","Console","1","22,348 K"
"chrome.exe","2580","Console","1","38,432 K"
"chrome.exe","3312","Console","1","32,756 K"
"chrome.exe","4600","Console","1","36,072 K"
"chrome.exe","4180","Console","1","24,436 K"
"chrome.exe","4320","Console","1","31,152 K"
"chrome.exe","4120","Console","1","22,632 K"
```

Exploiting this with the `csv` module, you now have:

```
>>> r = os.popen('tasklist /FI "STATUS eq Not Responding" /FO CSV')
>>> import csv
>>> reader = csv.DictReader(r, delimiter=',')
>>> rows = list(reader)
>>> rows[0]
{'Session Name': 'Console', 'Mem Usage': '13,352 K', 'PID': '3596', 'Image Name'
: 'jusched.exe', 'Session#': '1'}
>>> rows[0]['PID']
'3596'
```

I got rid of the `/NH` switch (No Header) to get dictionaries from the csv module.

Comment: Works well, however, I can't seem to make it automatically get me the PID from the process name I want it to. I have to specify the # of the row. Lets say process on row 7 is named fun.exe and I want only the PID associated with 'fun.exe' how could that be done?

Answer (score 0):

I reckon there is a method to get the process pid only, but if you want to know how to extract a specific substring from a string use regex

The regex pattern to match the pid : `\w+\.\w+\s+(\d+)\s`

```
import os
import re

r = os.popen('tasklist /FI "STATUS eq Not Responding"').read().strip()
print re.findall('\w+\.\w+\s+(\d+)\s',r)
```

Output:

```
['4024']
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [How to extract a specific field from output of tasklist on the windows command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507902/how-to-extract-a-specific-field-from-output-of-tasklist-on-the-windows-command-l):

```
print os.popen('for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %F in (\'tasklist /nh /fi "STATUS eq Not Responding" /fo csv\') do @echo %~F').read().strip()
```