# Join two commands in dos and get the final out put

Tags: findstr, netstat, tasklist, batch-file

Please can someone kindly help me to join these two commands

```
netstat -ano | findstr 0.0.0.0:80
```

The output is as follows

[image]

Then need to pipe out PID results to next command that is

```
tasklist | findstr <PID from previous netstat command>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13507902 may help get you part way there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=5" %%# in ('netstat -ano ^| findstr "0.0.0.0:80"') do set "pid=%%#"
tasklist | findstr "%pid%"
```

or from command line:

```
for /f "tokens=5" %# in ('netstat -ano ^| findstr "0.0.0.0:80"') do set "pid=%#"
```

To get process name
from command line:

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=5" %a in ('qprocess %pid%') do set "image=%a"
```

from

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=5" %%a in ('qprocess %pid%') do set "image=%%a"
```

It uses already created variable %pid%

Comment: thanks for great support.. but it gives final output as set "pid=5568" .. what i wish is to have task name grepped from tasklist according to pid

Comment: @echo off
for /f "tokens=5" %%# in ('netstat -ano ^| findstr "0.0.0.0:80"') do set "pid=%%#"
tasklist | findstr "%pid%"    is perfect.. its working as expected when saved to a bat file