# Build cmd command to extract PID from tasklist and use condition on the result

Tags: windows, cmd, tasklist

I'm trying to write **one line** cmd command that:

- execute `tasklist` with PID filter
- iterate over the output

  - do something if PID found
  - do something else if PID was not found

So I've read [How to extract a specific field from output of tasklist on the windows command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13507902/1798187) and used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13516882/1798187) to construct this command:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %F in ('tasklist /nh /fi "PID eq 5284" /fo csv') do if %F NEQ "5284" (@echo no) else  (@echo yes)
```

I didn't get the expected result. Most likely got the syntax wrong.

Comment: The loop's command only executes if PID 5284 exists. Try this: `(for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %F in ('tasklist /nh /fo csv /fi "PID eq 5284"') do @echo yes) || @echo no`.

Comment: @eryksun That's great. post an answer and I'll accept. 10x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just posting the answer commented by eryksun:

> (for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %F in ('tasklist /nh /fo csv /fi "PID eq
>   5284"') do @echo yes) || @echo no